# multiple line on same plot for timeseries

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

Below table has 366 days of data:

```
od
    month dayofmonth total    ad  aont
1       1          1    27     9    18
2       1          2    31    24     7
3       1          3    30    25     5
4       1          4    29    15    14
5       1          5    27     1    26
6       1          6    30    18    12
7       1          7    31     8    23
8       1          8    30     9    21
9       1          9    25    23     2
10      1         10    31    15    16
11      1         11    27    17     7
12      1         12    27     3    24
13      1         13    26    11    15
14      1         14    28    12    


library(zoo)
require(xts)

Dates <- seq(as.Date(f, "%Y - %m - %d"), as.Date(t, "%Y - %m - %d"), "day")


total<- xts(od$total, order.by = Dates)
dont<- xts(od$ad, order.by = Dates)
adont<- xts(od$aont, order.by = Dates)
```

I used `zoo` package now I want to draw multiple lines in same plot

Answer (score 0):

Create the zoo object and then plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

z <- zoo(od[3:5], as.Date(paste(2012, od$month, od$dayofmonth, sep = "-")))

autoplot(z, facet = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `plot.type="single"` in the plot call can help with this.

```
    #open libraries 
library(xts)
library(zoo)
#set some random variables
a=rnorm(100)
b=rnorm(100)
#and some time series
c=seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "week", length.out = 100)
d=cbind(a,b)
#make it into an zoo object
d=as.zoo(d, order.by=c)
plot.zoo(d, 
         plot.type = "single", 
         col = c("red", "blue"))
```